# SQL script to generate another [INSERT] SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a weird SQL situation in which I need to create a SQL script that I would run against database A and it would output another SQL script that would contain `INSERT` statements which I can then run against database B and upload the data (essentially an Export from A to B but a longer way).

I was wondering if anyone has worked on this an can suggest a way to generate `INSERT` statements that would contain data from `[Database A].[Table Student]` which can then be uploaded to `[Database B].[Table Student]`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depending on the version, there are easier ways. For example you could export a .dacpac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat the values from student into an insert string like:

```
SELECT concat('Insert INTO Students VALUES(', Col1,', ', '''', Col2, '''', ')')
     AS [Details]
     FROM Student
     WHERE ...
```

N.B The four single quotes is to create a single quote before and after varchar columns for example.

To generate a new SQL script from this, I'd create a cmd file with something like:

```
SET SERVER=YOUR_SERVER
SET DATABASE=YOUR_DB

sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h -1 -i Script.sql -o NewScript.sql -W
```

Comment: This is just what I needed...Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

--  You Can Simple Use insert into statement

```
INSERT INTO [Database B].[Table Student]
SELECT * FROM [Database A].[Table Student] 
WHERE StudentID NOT IN (SELECT  StudentID FROM  [Database B].[Table Student])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that would insert data from one database table to other database table

```
INSERT INTO [DestinationDB].[dbo].Student
SELECT * FROM [SourceDB].[dbo].Student
GO
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I know this is a much simpler and "more logical" way but I need to create a script that would output another script containing INSERT stmts. Weird, I know :(.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the both databases you can do it in one query like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Database A].[Table Student]
OUTPUT inserted.*
INTO [Database B].[Table Student]
SELECT *
FROM [newdata];
```